# Cacti email notifications on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cacti

Im new to Ubuntu and Cacti, so please excuse me...

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04 Server and cacti v0.8.8b. Plugin architecture is v3.1

I would like to configure email notifications for downed hosts, so i installed the settings and monitor plugin.

I have attached the [settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHvVZ.jpg)

When i configure it to use SMTP the following error is given - 
SMTP Host does not appear to support authentication: 503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled.

If i use the PHP mailer the following is displayed - 
Unable to send email with php mail function, check your system logs (i have no idea as to where this log file is)

Can someone pls help me to configure it, or at least point me in the right direction, as i have no clue on where to start.

Thanks in advance,
Kevin

Comment: You _just installed_ Ubuntu 15.04? [Ubuntu 15.04 reached end of life February 4, 2016](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

Comment: Yeah, cause I couldn't get cacti to install on 16.04 :(

Comment: Well then you should maybe be looking at 14.04 LTS